# How to access property of an element ar specified index inside array?

Tags: powershell, pipe

Lets say I have the following script:

```
$processes = Get-Process
$thirdProcess = $processes[2]
$thirdProcess.Id
```

How to write it in a single line using pipe?

Why does something like this not work?

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -Index 0 | $.Id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this (`ps` is an alias for `Get-Process`)

```
ps | select -Index 2 | select -expand Id
```

Or very short (without using pipes):

```
(ps)[2].Id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -Index 0 | ForEach-Object -MemberName Id
```

Or short-hand:

```
ps | select -Index 0 | % Id
```